# where to store external javascript library in OBIEE

Tags: obiee

We use OBIEE 11g and 12. We want to use an external javascript library for a specific analyse. This library we have to store somewhere on the server. In analytics I have to import this library with the tag

```
<script src="/somewhereOnTheServer/myscripts.js"></script>
```

Can someone tell me where I have to store those libraries and what is the src to point at ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can literally use any path / location which your web app server can reach.

Normally I put it into a proper custom deployment though to have it compartmentalized and in an easy-to-integrate place in terms of deployments and source control.

You can reference the analyticsRes approach to to this: https://gianniceresa.com/2017/02/obiee-12c-custom-style-using-shared-folder/